# Testing websocket connection in multiple tabs makes the page upresponsive

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, websocket

I am trying to test the memory consumption for multiple websocket connection to my webpage. The website is hosted in local IIS server. I load the same page in different tabs and establish a websocket connection for data transfer. Problem is it only allows me to do it on three occation. When i open the page on the fourth tab the page does not load and keeps loading. I tried seperate browser profiles also but same result. If i close one of the previous tabs, the fourth tab which was showing loading, immediately loads.

Can anyone please help. Do i need to configure something on IIS or my application?

PS: My code and app runs fine in windows server but its causing problem in windows 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, see for you machine.config and add/edit this lines:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="500"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

will have a maximum of 500 simultaneous connections
Search machine.config file in this directories:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
```

Sorry for my bad english xD!!

Comment: still having same problem :(